# Android Volley Error

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I get Android volley error suddenly when i run my program.here i paste my AppController class for handling the volley objects.

**AppController.java**

```
public class AppController extends Application {
public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
}
```

and i call this class in some another class of my program like

> AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

it will executed without any errors in so many days but now it shows error
like

**Error:**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setTag(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/android/volley/Request; in class Lcom/android/volley/Request or its super classes (declaration of 'com.android.volley.Request'; appears in /data/app/com.example.rninja4.rookie-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes6.dex)
                                                                          at com.example.packagename.App.AppController.addToRequestQueue(AppController.java:39)
```

Comment: attach  your gradle app file and manifiest file with question

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared application class in manifest like below.

```
<application
    android:name="AppController"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: did you try with full qualified name of AppController class.

Comment: yes . i tried still its not working and the app is running without this error in so many days ,i get this error suddenly.

Comment: Here Volley gradle suggested. please change volley gradle and try .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370743/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-virtual-method-settagljava-lang-object

Comment: Next i want to know that if there is any sudden changes in library how can i solve that.